# ¿Cómo actualizar valor de una tabla cuando el valor de otra tabla cambie?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Tengo con nombre **Empresa** una tabla con una columna que es de con nombre **Estatus** de tipo *ENUM('Activo','Inactivo')* y en otra tabla con nombre **Cupos** con una columna de nombre **No_Cupos** de tipo *INT*.

Lo que yo quiero hacer es que cuando **No_Cupos** tenga un valor de 0 la coumna **Estatus** pase a ***Inactivo***, las 2 ya están relacionadas con llave foránea.

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Puedes usar un trigger de update. Aqui una pregunta similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296313/mysql-trigger-after-update-only-if-row-has-changed

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte, debes intentar algo y modificar la pregunta añadiendo el código de tu intento